# Magento 2 product collection sorting is not working (I am doing with custom attribute)

Tags: collections, magento2, product

This is my code

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('article_position', 'DESC');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_productCollection->getdata());
```

**OR**

```
$_productCollection->setOrder('article_position', 'DESC');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_productCollection->getdata());
```

But collection data is same no effect in my collection why ?

Comment: $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->setOrder('article_position', 'DESC');

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to change sort order of product collection:

```
$_productCollection->getSelect()
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER)
    ->order('article_position', 'DESC');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_productCollection->getData());
```

Note "article_position" is an custom attribute